# Can't get past or select dropdown when entering name for Destination

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to self learn Selenium, but I am not able to figure out how to close or select from a dropdown which opens once I enter destination into input box.

```js
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Dropdown {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/Karthik/Desktop/Education/Selenium Short/geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64/geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver D= new FirefoxDriver ();
            D.get("https://www.kayak.com/flights");
            System.out.println(D.getCurrentUrl());
            D.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='One-way']")).click();
            D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='origin']")).clear();
            D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='origin']")).sendKeys("TPA");
            D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).sendKeys("DEL");
            D.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[class()='airportCode']")).click();
            WebElement abc=D.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='ap selected']"));
            Alert Work=D.switchTo().alert();
            Work.accept();
            abc.click();

            D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.//span[text()='Depart']")).sendKeys("02/21/2017");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
    D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

after :

```
  D.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).sendKeys("DEL");
```

Comment: Kushal sir, the suggestion didn't close or select the dropdown :(

Comment: Why do you need to close it? You can just provide a relevant airport code and move along.

Comment: After entering airport code dropdown displays and without clicking it my script isnt moving forward. Code shows its in "Li" instead of ui when I inspect.

Comment: Try as following:

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='origin']")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='origin']")).sendKeys("TPA");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='origin']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).sendKeys("DEL");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='destination']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);